# Appending pandas dataframe issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a TWO dataframes which has 2100 rows × 857 columns. I want to append the 2nd one to the first one.

I use `X_train_features = X_train_features.append(X_train_Specfeatures, ignore_index= True)`
for this. But instead of getting 4200 rows x 857 columns I get a dataframe of 4200 rows x 1714 columns.

Check out below images.

This is first dataframe.
[image: dataframe 1]

This is the 2nd one.
[image: 2nd dataframe]

The output I get by appending is
[image: End result]

I am not able to understand what is wrong.

Comment: This usually happens when the column names are different, can you please include `X_train_features.info()` and `X_train_Specfeatures.info()` ? copy the text and paste into a code block

Answer (score 2):

In Fact what you want is to concatenate the two data frames.

You can use pd.concat()

```
pd.concat([first_df,second_df],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

the usual way to merge two dataframe is to use pandas .concat() function. You must then specify axis = 0 to merge the dataframe according to the label of the columns:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"a":[7,8,9],"b":[10,11,12]})
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
```

Comment: if the problem is that the columns are not labeled the same in both dfs, then `concat` would have the same effect as `append` wouldn't it?

Comment: @RichieV if your columns are not named the same thing, you need to correct that.

Comment: @PaulH that is precisely my point, the OP seems to be having that problem

Comment: you can then give the same labels to your df2 for example like this: df2.columns = df1.columns but make sure that the columns are in the right order.

Comment: @RichieV Oops. Sorry. I thought you were the OP

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can solve your specific problem with

```
X_train_Specfeatures.columns = X_train_features.columns
```

---

**Background**

As mentioned in the comments, that usually happens when the column labels are not the same for both dfs.

Take these two dfs

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
df2 = df.copy()
```

If you `append` (or `concat`, all the same), you will get a 4x2 df because the column labels are exactly the same.

```
# df_out = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df_out = pd.concat([df, df2])

print(df_out)

   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  0  1
3  2  3
```

But if you change the column names in one df you will get a 4x4 df, because pandas tries to align the column labels.

```
df2.columns = ['0', '1']

# df_out = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df_out = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

print(df_out)

     0    1    0    1
0  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0
3  NaN  NaN  2.0  3.0
```

Notice even though the column names are printed the same, they are actually different values (in one df `0` is an integer and in the other it is a string). So pandas interprets them as different columns, and since the second df has no values for the first column, then it fills with `NaN`.

You can read more in this question about [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/6692898)